# How do I take a .csv file and add it as a worksheet to a PHPExcel object?

Tags: phpexcel

I create a sheet

```
    $xls = new PHPExcel();
    $xls->addSheet('my sheet');
```

I create an object to read a .csv

```
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('myfile.csv');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($myFileName);
```

Is there a short way to place all the rows from the csv into the current worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worksheet object has `fromArray()` and `toArray()` methods, so why not use those?

```
$xls->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray(
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray()
    );
```

Otherwise you can iterate over `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()` reading cells, or rows at a time, then inserting them into `$xls->getActiveSheet()`